# Usage of strtol on std::string

Tags: c++, string

I recently migrated from C to C++, and there's a little confusion about strings. Strings just aren't what they used to be any more, as in, not just char arrays with a terminating '\0'.
I haven't found a real answer to this question, so how far can you treat the std::string class like C-Strings?

For example: If I know there's a number somewhere in a string, let the string be `ireallylike314`, in C I could use `strtol(string + 10, NULL, 10)` to just get that number.
And, if this doesn't work, is there a way to use std::string like C-strings?

Comment: `string[10]` does the same thing in C...

Comment: string[10] in this case works like string+10, and gives you the string at that offset in this case.. Or am I wrong?

Comment: `string[10]` stands for `*(string + 10)`, not `(string + 10)`.

Comment: Oh damn you're right. I confused myself, I'm sorry. I will change that to string+10

Comment: Use [`stol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) for `std::string` objects.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `stol` can't do everything that `strtol` can. In particular, it cannot do this very thing the OP wants.

Comment: This is pretty vague. Figure out what you want to do with your string, _specifically_, then look up how to do that thing.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes It can, using `substr`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `c_str()`.

```
strtol(string.c_str() + 10, NULL, 10);
```

Comment: @Mgetz, did you read the question? _"in C I could use `strtol(string + 10, NULL, 10)`"_

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get C-style string from `std::string`, then as mentioned use `c_str()` method. But another solution to this specific problem would be just using [`stol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) instead of `strtol`.

Comment: `stol` wouldn't work because it cannot work directly with the middle of the string.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I forgot about it, but you can get a middle of a string using `substr` method.

Answer (score 2):

While `stol` doesn't (in itself) support what you want, I think I'd use it in conjunction with `substr` to get the required result:

```
std::string in = "ireallylike314";

// extract number and print it out multiplied by 2 to show we got a number
std::cout << 2 * stol(in.substr(11));
```

Result:

```
628
```

This has both good and bad points though. On the bad side, it creates a whole new string object to hold the digits out of the input string. On the good side, it gives a little more control over the number of digits to convert, so if (for example) you only wanted to convert the first two digits from the string (even if, as in this case, they're followed by more digits) you can do that pretty easily too:

```
std::cout << 2 * stol(in.substr(11, 2));
```

Result:

```
62
```

In quite a few cases, the degree to which this is likely to be practical for you will depend heavily upon whether your implementation includes the short string optimization. If it does, creating a (small) string is often cheap enough to make this perfectly reasonable. If it doesn't, the heap allocation to create the temporary string object as the return value from `substr` may be a higher price than you want to pay.

Comment: if you check the code `boost::string_ref` has an implementation of `stol` that is a call through to `strtol` that maintains safety

Answer (score 1):

The C-like way:

```
long n = std::strtol( string.c_str() + offset, nullptr, 10 );
// sets ERRNO on error and returns value by saturating arithmetic.
```

The Java-ish way:

```
long n = std::stol( string.substr( offset, std::string::npos ) );
// exception (no return value) and perhaps ERRNO is set on error.
```

The streams way:

```
long n = 0;
std::istringstream( string ).ignore( offset ) >> n;
// n is unmodified on error
```

The locales way:

```
long n = 0;
std::ios_base fmt; // Use default formatting: base-10 only.
std::ios::iostate err = {};
std::num_get< char, std::string::iterator >()
            .get( string.begin() + offset, string.end(), fmt, err, n );
// err is set to std::ios::failbit on error
```

Answer (score 0):

> Strings just aren't what they used to be any more, as in, not just
>   char arrays with a terminating '\0'.

You are wrong. In C++ strings are defined the same way. In both languages strings are defined like

> A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and
>   including the first null character.

You mix strings with class `std::string` (or `std::basic_string`) that are not the same.

> For example: If I know there's a number somewhere in a string, let the
>   string be ireallylike314, in C I could use strtol(string[10], NULL,
>   10) to just get that number

You are mistaken. The valid function call will look like

```
strtol( &string[11], NULL, 10)
```

or

```
strtol( string + 11, NULL, 10)
```

The same function you can call for an object of class `std::string` using member function `c_str()` or (starting from C++ 2011) `data()`

For example

```
std::string s( "ireallylike314" );

auto x = std::strtol( s.c_str() + 11, NULL, 10 );
```

or

```
auto x = std::strtol( s.data() + 11, NULL, 10 );
```

Comment: He is not "wrong". There is obviously a big difference between a `std::string` and a `char[N]`, regardless of similarities between the latter and part of the implementation of the former.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit  Class std::string (or std::basic_string) and the notion of strings  are different things.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe beyond the scope of the question but since you are migrating to C++ and you seem confused about std::string, you'll likely find the following useful.

The point of having std::string is not to use it like C-Strings (ofc you can do it, like the previous answers showed). You can take a lot more advantages of std::string capabilities. For example it is a [C++ container](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/), there are functions to get substrings, to compare strings, etc ...

String manipultions are generally a lot easier with std::string rather than C-Strings.

See for example http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ for its capabilities.